# Print date and time for the beginning of the current week (in bash)

Tags: macos, datetime

I'm on Mac OSX.

I need the Unix date for the start of the week (midnight on Sunday). The correct answer for this week should be `1521331200`

`date -v -Sun +%s` gives me the right date, but the current time, `1521382825` or (roughly) Sun 18 Mar 2018 14:20:00 GMT.

Comment: depending on date version `TZ` environment variable can be used to specify timezone or `-u` option for utc: `date -u -d 'last Sun' +%s`

Comment: What version of `date` *are* you using?

Comment: I am wondering, which version of linux does not have Gnu date? Or is the `date` you are using here the one shipped with Mac OSX? Then you should add the tag `macos`. Besides `date` is a seperate program, not a `bash` bultin,  so the tag `bash` should be removed.

Comment: @nlu edited as requested - I was on a Mac targeting a Linux container, but that wasn't really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-v` multiple times.

```
% date -v -Sun
Sun Mar 18 10:53:29 EDT 2018
% date -v -Sun -v 0H -v 0M -v 0S
Sun Mar 18 00:00:00 EDT 2018
```